# How to handle get/post in Express 4/nodejs from app.js passing data from form to new page displaying results

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am sure this is a ridiculously easy question but I think I have a mental block now about answering it.

I have installed node.js and express 4 and I can run static pages without any problem. What I want to do is to create a form to capture some data and then display the data I captured in the form in a results page. I am using Jade to handle the HTML part.

In the app.js file those were the only things I changed:

..

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
// new routes
var helloworld = require('./routes/helloworld');
var sampleform = require('./routes/sampleform');
```

...

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
// new pages
app.get('/helloworld', helloworld);
app.get('/sampleform', sampleform);
```

I have a simple sampleform.jade file:

```
html
    head
        title Sample Form
    body
        h2 Sample Form
        form(name='sampleform' action='/sampleform' method='post')
            table(border='0')
                tr
                    td Name
                    td 
                        input(name='name' type='text' size='30')
                tr
                    td Email
                    td
                        input(name='email' type='text' size='30')
                tr
                    td
                        input(type='submit', name='submit', value='Submit')
```

I am able to load the form without problems using the following sampleform.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET sample form page. */
router.get('/sampleform', function(req, res) {
    res.render('sampleform');
});

router.post('/showresults', function(req, res) {
    res.render('showresults')
});

module.exports = router;
```

showresults.jade currently has only static content (I do not have a showresuls.js as this page is only called from sampleform.js):

```
html
    head
        title Show Results
    body
        h2 Show Results
```

What I need is that after the button submit is clicked in sampleform the new page called showresults is displayed (it will eventually have the data from sampleform but all I need right now is to have that page loaded). The code in sampleform.js above generates a 404 error and I know it does not work. What can I do instead? Am I missing something in the app.js code?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you're submitting the form to a `GET` route rather than a `POST` route in your Jade file, here:

`form(name='sampleform' action='/sampleform' method='post')`

So rather than sending the form submission to that `GET` request, you'll need to send it to a `POST`. You have declared a `POST` route here:

`router.post('/showresults', function(req, res) {`

So, you should only change the `action` from the form in your Jade file to point to `/showresults` because it's a `POST` route rather than the `GET /sampleform`. From there, you'll only need to call `req.body` to retrieve the whole form you previously submitted.

Comment: Thank you! That definitely pointed me on the right direction. I think I was trying to make things more complicated that they should be.